# React router always renders first route in nested component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

In the component rendered by react-router i have another routes. However, from these nested routes always only first route is rendered regardless actual path.
I read about update blocking and tried to wrap components into withRouter() but it didnt help.

I read about update blocking and tried to wrap components into withRouter() but it didnt help.
Reordering routes gives the same behavior.

App.js

```
class App extends Component{
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Router>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
                        <PrivateRoute path="/" component={Main}  />
                    </Switch>
                </Router>
                <Modal />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Main.js

```
class Main extends Component{
    render(){
        return (
            <div className="full-height flex-container flex-column">

                <div style={{display: "flex", flexDirection: "row", height: "100%"}}>
                    <NavigationBar items={[{name: 'Categories', route: '/'}, {name: 'Products', route: '/products'}]} />
                    <Content />
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Content.js and problematic routes itself

```
class Content extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div style={{ width: "100%"}}>
               <Switch>
                    <Route exact to="/" component={CategoriesPage} />
                    <Route to="/products" component={ProductsPage} />
               </Switch>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

I expect for path "/" - CategoriesPage to be rendered, and for "/products" - ProductsPage, but now CategoriesPage rendered for both "/" and "/products".
Thanks in advance.
Sample available here: https://codesandbox.io/s/github/nomernabis/login-flow-redux.

Comment: How are you navigating?, Though links or though URL. Is the URL changing?

Comment: Yes url is changing. I tried navigating both through the links, that triggers this.props.history.push(), and typed directly into browser url. Behavior is the same.

Comment: Try `<Route component={Content} />` instead of `<Content />` and see if it changes anything. Apart from it your code looks fine to me

Comment: I tried, still the same.

Comment: Can you create a demo of your issue on `codesandbox.io` or similar

Comment: There it is: https://codesandbox.io/s/github/nomernabis/login-flow-redux

Comment: In your Content class, replace `to`, use `path` instead. Does it solve your problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing your routes `to` instead of `path` in `Content.js`

working implementation here: https://codesandbox.io/s/mm10x7150p

```
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={CategoriesPage} />
      <Route exact path="/products" component={ProductsPage} />
    </Switch>
```